# Convert image sequence to video using Moviepy

Tags: python-3.x, moviepy

I tried to convert PNG images to video by list images in directory

```
clips[]
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
  if filename.endswith(".png"):
    clips.append(ImageClip(filename))
```

[image]

Then convert it

```
video = concatenate(clips, method='compose')
video.write_videofile('test.mp4')
```

The error is:
[image]
Full code

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import *


clips = []
base_dir = os.path.realpath(".")
print(base_dir)

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
  if filename.endswith(".png"):
    clips.append(ImageClip(filename))

video = concatenate(clips, method='compose')
video.write_videofile('test.mp4')
```

Comment: The link in the image is broken.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found another way to do it:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

img = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png', '6.png',
       '7.png', '8.png', '9.png', '10.png', '11.png', '12.png']

clips = [ImageClip(m).set_duration(2)
      for m in img]

concat_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")
concat_clip.write_videofile("test.mp4", fps=24)
```

And from current folder:

```
import os
import glob
from natsort import natsorted
from moviepy.editor import *

base_dir = os.path.realpath("./images")
print(base_dir)

gif_name = 'pic'
fps = 24

file_list = glob.glob('*.png')  # Get all the pngs in the current directory
file_list_sorted = natsorted(file_list,reverse=False)  # Sort the images

clips = [ImageClip(m).set_duration(2)
         for m in file_list_sorted]

concat_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")
concat_clip.write_videofile("test.mp4", fps=fps)
```

Comment: I used the current folder implementation. I have only 13 image frames and I set my fps to 25, but why does the output file takes 26 second? so slow. it must take less than 1 seconds. Why?

Comment: @Eliyah Probably because `set_duration(2)` sets it to two seconds per image.

Comment: The natsort was what was missing for me, my files were sorted alphanumerically but not naturally as the program would expect, good one

Answer (score 8):

This is how I did it using your initial code. The error you were seeing was due to not specifying `set_duration` for the clips. I also sorted the files in the directory so that the resulting mp4 is sequential (was not the case by default).

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import *

base_dir = os.path.realpath(".")
print(base_dir)
directory=sorted(os.listdir('.'))
print(directory)

for filename in directory:
  if filename.endswith(".png"):
    clips.append(ImageClip(filename).set_duration(1))

print(clips)
video = concatenate(clips, method="compose")
video.write_videofile('test1.mp4', fps=24)
```