# Making video from clips on moviepy only showing last image

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm trying to make a video from a list of images using moviepy. I have issues using `moviepy.editor` since it does not like being frozen using PyInstaller, so I'm using `moviepy.video.VideoClip.ImageClip` for the images and `moviepy.video.compositing.CompositeVideoClip.CompositeVideoClip` for the clip. I have a list of `.jpg` images in a list called `images`:

```
from moviepy.video.VideoClip import ImageClip
from moviepy.video.compositing.CompositeVideoClip import CompositeVideoClip

clips = [ImageClip(m).set_duration(1) for m in images]
concat_clip = CompositeVideoClip(clips))
concat_clip.write_videofile('VIDEO.mp4', fps=1)
```

It successfully makes an `.mp4` but the video is only one second long and the last image in the list of images. I can check `clips` and it has the ~30 images that should be in the video. I can do this from using methods from `moviepy.editor` following [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732602/convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-moviepy), but there doesn't seem to be an analogous parameter in `CompositeVideoClip` for `method='compose'` which is where I think the issue is.

Comment: set_duration is set to 1? and why is your fps1? If you just deal wth images, ffmpeg does a much better and faster job: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/ffmpeg-create-video-from-images

Comment: I know ffmpeg would be better, but I cannot use it at my work. I have `set_duration` and `fps` set to 1 because each image should be shown for 1 second and the video will be at 1 fps just to make the file size as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

using concatenate_videoclips might help. I use the code below and it works just fine.

```py
clips = [ImageClip(m).set_duration(1/25)
         for m in file_list_sorted]
concat_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")
concat_clip.write_videofile("test.mp4", fps=25)
```